# How to search from the root of project - Ag / VIM

Tags: vim, ag

I did add `let g:ag_working_path_mode="r"` to my `.vimrc` but it doesn't work when I tried to search for example `:Ag! jquery` in `/vagrant/my_prj/app/Controller/MyController.php [Git(master)]` and I get `No matches for "jquery"`

But if searched `:Ag! jquery /vagrant/my_prj` I get around 800 results.

I do have `.git` folder in `/vagrant/my_prj/` folder.

Comment: *Always* start Vim from the root of your project and *never* change directory if you don't absolutely need to.

Comment: @romainl Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want vim to always cd to the project's root directory, you could use the plugin called rooter: "Rooter changes the working directory to the project root when you open a file or directory."

see: https://github.com/airblade/vim-rooter